# Buttons center their children when they are placed in a ListView.builder widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do buttons in Flutter tend to align their children to the centre when they are placed in list views?

For example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return MaterialButton(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text("Hello"),
              ],
            ));
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This would result in ten hellos spaced evenly by the default height of the button, but they would be centered; even though I used the `CrossAxisAlignment.start` property in a column.

Here is the image:

[image]

But when I replace the MaterialButton with a Container they are aligned to the start to the column as wanted.

When I just remove the `ListView.Builder` I get 'hello' aligned to the start.

The same thing happens with the rest of the buttons.
Is there a way to make buttons in list views not have centered children inside them?

**Edit:** the example was fixed by @Harry but it didn't fix my exact code

here is my code: I try to created a list of widgets outside and use a function to add my list items into that list and return a list view through the `ActivitiesList` widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:list_them_out/models/activities.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ActivitiesList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ActivitiesListState createState() => _ActivitiesListState();
}

double conBorderRadius = 30;

class _ActivitiesListState extends State<ActivitiesList> {
  List<Widget> itemData = [];

  void getData(context) {
    double cardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3;
    double cardWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.97;
    final activities = Provider.of<List<Activity>>(context);

    activities == null
    // ignore: unnecessary_statements
        ? null
        : setState(() {
      itemData = [];
    });

    activities == null
    // ignore: unnecessary_statements
        ? null
        : setState(() {
      activities.forEach((element) {
        itemData.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Container(
              width: cardWidth,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(conBorderRadius),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.lightGreen[300],
                      Colors.lightBlue[300],
                    ]
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                        offset: Offset(4.0, 4.0),
                        blurRadius: 15,
                        spreadRadius: 1),
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        offset: Offset(-4.0, -4.0),
                        blurRadius: 15,
                        spreadRadius: 1),
                  ]),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(conBorderRadius),
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      splashColor: HSLColor.fromColor(Colors.green).toColor(),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Container(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    width: cardWidth * 0.61,
                                    child: Text(
                                      element.name,
                                      maxLines: 2,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                                        fontSize: 25,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        letterSpacing: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: cardHeight * 0.09, left: cardWidth * 0.03),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: cardWidth * 0.48,
                                      child: RichText(
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                                          TextSpan(
                                            text: "Start: ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.grey[800],
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                letterSpacing: 1),
                                          ),
                                          TextSpan(
                                              text: element.time,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black87,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                                fontSize: 20,
                                              ))
                                        ]),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: cardHeight * 0.06,),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.comment),
                                        onPressed: () => null,
                                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                                        child: Text("Comments", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, letterSpacing: 1),),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    child: ClipPath(
                      clipper: MyClip(radius: conBorderRadius),
                      child: Container(
                        height: cardHeight,
                        width: cardWidth * 0.45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                colors: <Color>[
                                  Colors.grey[300],
                                  Colors.lightBlue[100].withOpacity(0.5)
                                ])),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  Positioned(
                    right: cardWidth * 0.05,
                    bottom: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text("Hello"),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ));
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double listHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.86;
    double listWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.97;

    getData(context);

    return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(50), topLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
        child: Container(
          height: listHeight,
          width: listWidth,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: itemData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
                  child: itemData[index],
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}

``
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget. Just wrap the column with an align widget and have the alignment parameter be [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment-class.html).[centerLeft](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Alignment/centerLeft-constant.html).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return MaterialButton(
            child: Align(
                child:Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                        Text("Hello"),
                    ],
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            )
        );
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked on the given example but not in my actual code :(

Comment: what did you write in your code? Just make sure you wrap whatever is in your button widget with and align widget.

Comment: A `Container` then  a `Stack` as its child then a `ClipRRect` on the `MaterialButton` then the a `Column` that I wrapped with `Align` with the `Alignment.centerLeft` property

Comment: did you try to put an align widget before the column and have the alignment set to centerLeft?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: perhaps try wrapping the stack and the column. just keep trying to wrap stuff and align them to the left and check if it aligns to the left. But at least you know the button isn't the problem anymore.

Comment: No, the button is the problem, when I replace the `MaterialButton` with a `Container` they are aligned to the left automatically without using `Align` just with the `CrossAxisAlignment.start` property

Comment: have you tried wrapping the child of Align with a Container?